# Why is my query not working for room.slug

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Currently, I am trying there are 4 categories, each categories have 4 rooms. I am trying to write the view to enter that particular room but somehow even though I can render the page, what i query doesn't work.Why is this so?

Which means when I do `{{ room_slug }}` or `{{room.slug}}`, nothing comes out

function-based views.py

```
def room_view(request, category_slug, room_slug):
    context = {}
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    room = Room.objects.filter(slug=room_slug,typeofcategory=category)
    context['room'] = room
    return render(request, "room.html", context)
```

template

```
{{ room.slug }}
```

urls.py

```
    path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:room_slug>/', room_view , name= "room"),
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    type_of_category = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False, blank=False, choices=type_of_category_CHOICES, default=True, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

class Room(models.Model):
    typeofcategory = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='typeofcategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` returns a Queryset and not the instance of the Model. You likely want to use `get` instead:

```
room = Room.objects.get(slug=room_slug,typeofcategory=category)
```

In fact just use `get_object_or_404` for ease:

```
room = get_object_or_404(Room, slug=room_slug, typeofcategory=category)
```